# Using a Google Analytics custom dimension for pageview statistics widget

Tags: google-analytics, custom-dimensions

I have a custom dimension that is being set with a gtag tracking code. I can actually see that the values are being send to GA and can, for example, make dashboard widgets with it.

The odd thing is that when I make a widget with sessions and the dimension it works well, but if I want to make a widget with pageviews and the dimension it returns no data at all.

This is my tracking code:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}

gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'UA-0000000-0', {"anonymize_ip":true,"custom_map":{"dimension1":"premium"}});

gtag('set', 'premium', {'premium': 'premium post and not subscribed'});
```

I've also, instead of using 'set' tried using 'event' but this did not solve the issue. It looks like the custom dimension is not being collected with pageviews, but with sessions only.

Does anyone know if I have to configure it differently to also make it work for pageviews?

Comment: What scope is your dimension configured as? User/Session/Hit?

Comment: @vinoaj It is set on 'Hit'.

Comment: the hit dimension scope would show no data for pages where the no CD hits where detected. Try using `includeEmptyRows`  parameter set to `true` in your API request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your custom dimension is configured at the hit level it needs to be associated with either an `event` or `pageview` hit. Your code looks like it simply sets the custom dimension value, but it's not followed by a `pageview` hit call. Try swapping the idea of your calls instead:

```
gtag('set', 'premium', {'premium': 'premium post and not subscribed'});
gtag('config', 'UA-0000000-0', {"anonymize_ip":true,"custom_map":{"dimension1":"premium"}});
```